# In page link reloads page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, routes

I'm building my first Angular 2 app and I've come quite far now with a nice Webpack build system, routing, services and components in place.

I tried adding a normal in page link (`[href^="#"]`) in one of my components, and as long as I'm on the home page (`/`) it works fine, but whenever I'm on a different URL the whole app reloads to the home page.

Apparently this is a known issue (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595) but I need this to work right now so I'm hoping someone can teach me how.

I'm not sure it'll help, but here's my Component's TS and HTML:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    template: require('./home.component.html'),
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class HomeComponent {

}

<section id="home" class="section section--full-height">

    <h2>Title of the home page</h2>

    <nav>
        <a [routerLink]="['Search']" class="button button--wide">Search</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['Search']">Quick try</a>
    </nav>

    <footer>
        <a href="#home-2" class="icon-down icon--below">Heres how it works</a>
    </footer>

</section>

<section id="home-2" class="section section--full-height">

    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>

    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300">

</section>
```

As you can see it's the link "here's how it works" (or any other in page link - I have more than this one in reality) that only works (scrolls down to the linked element) when you're on the home page (`/`). If on any other URL, the link will reload the app.

Comment: Can you post  a snippet of the url you are using or the JavaScript you are writing for this ?

Comment: @AlvaroJoao not sure it'll help, but done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I've also learnt the hard way trying to develop a real-world app with angular2 before its release that you really should stay as far away from the current development as possible, especially in terms of the router(s).

The third iteration of the router is currently extremely alpha and I've run across so many issues that I've had to revert its implementation which as you likely know is quite a bit of work as the API has changed considerably.

As far as your issue is concerned though, I haven't actually found that any of the routers actually implement hashes correctly and I've had to get around this with a scroll component that looks something like the below:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[scroll-to-target-on-event]'
})
export class ScrollToTargetOnEventDirective {

  @Input('scroll-to-target-on-event') configs:Array<{target:Element, event:string}>;

  constructor(private _element:ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    for (let config of this.configs) {
      this._element.nativeElement.addEventListener(config.event, () => {
          // Get the position of the target relative to the entire page. getBoundingClientRect is relative to the
          // viewport so to get relative to the entire page we subtract the body (as we're looking to use scrollpos)
          var targetYPos = config.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top;

          // If the target position is below the bottom of the viewport then scroll to it. (This should actually
          // check above as well, haven't implemented it though)
          if (targetYPos > (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + (document.documentElement.clientHeight|| window.innerHeight)) {
            window.scrollTo(0, config.target.getBoundingClientRect().top - document.body.getBoundingClientRect().top);
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

You can then add this directive to an element on the given page.

```ts
<a href="" [scroll-to-target-on-event]="[{target: '#id-of-target-element', event:'click'}]">Link</a>
```

I hope this helps you solve your issue for the time being!

Comment: Thanks for this. However, scrolling to the element is in reality only half of what I'm trying to achieve. Ever since :target came to CSS I've used it to toggle visibility of anything from slide out menus to pop-ups. Here's hoping they solve this for release. I actually switched to Aurelia for now. Its router works at least. I still can't use :target though because of a webkit bug with pushState and :target not re-rendering. I'll give you the credit for supplying a solution to half the problem.

Comment: Cheers! The numerous routers that have been introduced have been a bit of a rollercoaster ride. I'll have to check out Aurelia as well.

Answer (score 4):

In case you don't want to modify anything:  [**PLUNKER DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/K9fffuhRDUx60awD5TKc?p=preview)

Just put this Directive in your Component, and you're done.

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: 'a[href^=#]',
  inputs: ['href'],
  host: {
    "(click)": "linkClicked($event)"
  }
})
export class InPageLinks {
  href: string;

  linkClicked(e){ // handles click event, only prevents the links with a # in the beginning

      e.preventDefault();
      this.scrollToID(this.href);
  }

  scrollToID(id){ // scrolls to the given id
    let target = document.querySelector(id);

    document.body.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;  
    // current scroll-target is body, you can take another input if you want
  }
}
```

Comment: It works but I need top of my element to get aligned with top of window. To do that I use target.scrollIntoView();

Answer (score 3):

In the current release of the router - version `3.0.0-alpha.8` - there is a way to add hash fragments to your links. However, the angular team still has some work to do to make it function properly.

On your anchor element, add a `fragment` attribute with the hash value.

If you want to generate a local link, just use this notation:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./']" fragment="Test">Jump to 'Test' anchor </a>
```

If you were at the location

```
www.example.org/Comp1/Comp2
```

before, this will change the URL to

```
www.example.org/Comp1/Comp2#Test
```

This will also work when linking to another component:

```
<a [routerLink]="['Comp3']" fragment="Test">Jump to 'Test' anchor </a>
```

which will take you to

```
www.example.org/Comp1/Comp2/Comp3#Test
```

#### However...

There still seems to be a bug in angular's implementation. Although the link is generated and updated correctly in the address bar of the browser, the browser does not jump to the specified hash location. It only does that, when you move your cursor into the address bar and hit enter, which obviously does not help.

I commented again on the github post referenced by @powerbuoy and @Günter-Zöchbauer to give the Angular team a heads up on the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm after except for the fact that it doesn't work the way it should :P I assume using :target in CSS doesn't work either? I already gave credit to Ian though.

Comment: I know, right?
Yeah, that's absolutely fine with me. He gave you a solution that works, so he deserves the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6595 was fixed recently and will be included in the next release (probably today)